# How to auto change item height after calling TextView setText when using RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, textview

I'm using RecyclerView and PagerSnapHelper to show some question needed user to answer. After loading data, I need to call `TextView.setText()` to change the title of the question. The item view of RecyclerView has property `android:layout_height="wrap_content"`, but it's not auto change the height after `setText()`.

if the title text need two lines to show(there is nothing wrong because my placeholder text need two line to show):
[image]

**Issue** if the title text need three lines to show:
[image]

So, my question is how to auto change the item-height after calling `TextView.setText()` in RecyclerView item.

item_evaluate_norm_view.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@drawable/round_bg">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/normTypeIV"
        android:layout_width="7dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/normTypeTV"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/normTypeTV"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/bg_pure_color_gray" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/normTypeTV"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
        android:text="@string/text_common_norm"
        android:textColor="@color/colorCommonText"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/line3"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/normTypeIV"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout13"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/normTypeTV"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/normTypeTV">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/totalItemCount"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:text="30"
            android:textColor="@color/colorCommonText"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/curItemPos" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/curItemPos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="1"
            android:textColor="@color/colorBasicBlack"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <View
        android:id="@+id/line3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:background="@color/colorFirstLvlBorder"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout13" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/normNameTV"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:text="实验室安全责任人明确且与学院签订了安全责任书"
        android:textSize="24sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryText"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/line3" />

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/radioGroup"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/normNameTV">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/itemEvaluateNormViewRBPassed"
            style="@style/checkbox_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
            android:text="@string/text_pass"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/itemEvaluateNormViewRBFailed"
            style="@style/checkbox_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
            android:text="@string/text_failed"
            android:checked="false"
            android:textSize="20sp" />
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView28"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="@string/text_text_describe"
        android:textSize="@dimen/info_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/colorInfo"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/radioGroup" />

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/constraintLayout14"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:background="@drawable/bg_common_border"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView28">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
            android:background="@null"
            android:singleLine="false"
            android:hint="@string/text_text_describe_hint"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="false"
            android:textColorHint="@color/colorPlaceholderText"
            android:textSize="@dimen/common_text_size"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:importantForAutofill="no" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView29"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:text="@string/text_prove_files"
        android:textColor="@color/colorInfo"
        android:textSize="@dimen/info_text_size"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/constraintLayout14" />

    <com.qmuiteam.qmui.widget.roundwidget.QMUIRoundButton
        android:id="@+id/lastItemBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="24dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/text_last_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/nextItemBtn"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView29"
        app:qmui_radius="@dimen/btn_radius" />

    <com.qmuiteam.qmui.widget.roundwidget.QMUIRoundButton
        android:id="@+id/nextItemBtn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/btn_height"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="24dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="@string/text_next_item"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/lastItemBtn"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView29"
        app:qmui_radius="@dimen/btn_radius" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

fragment_evaluate.xml

```xml
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/qmui_config_color_background">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/evaluateNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/roomNameTV"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="18sp"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/evaluateNameTV"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/evaluateNameTV" />

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/fragmentEvaluateNormRV"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/roomNameTV" />
    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

EvaluateFragment.java

```java
...
private void initRecyclerView() {
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(),
            LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false);

    RecyclerView rv = mBinding.fragmentEvaluateNormRV;
    rv.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    EvaluateNormRVAdapter adapter = new EvaluateNormRVAdapter();
    rv.setAdapter(adapter);

    EvaluateNormRVAdapter.OnClickListener lastOrNextClick =
            position -> layoutManager.smoothScrollToPosition(rv, new RecyclerView.State(), position);

    adapter.setNextItemListener(lastOrNextClick);
    adapter.setLastItemListener(lastOrNextClick);

    PagerSnapHelper pagerSnapHelper = new PagerSnapHelper();
    pagerSnapHelper.attachToRecyclerView(rv);
}
...
```

EvaluateNormRVAdapter.java

```java
public class EvaluateNormRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<EvaluateNormRVAdapter.ViewHolder> {
    private List<Norm> mItems;

    public EvaluateNormRVAdapter() {
        mItems = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    public void addItemBatch(int startPos, List<Norm> items) {
        mItems.addAll(items);
        notifyItemRangeInserted(startPos, items.size());
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int position) {
        ItemEvaluateNormViewBinding binding = ItemEvaluateNormViewBinding.inflate(
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()), parent, false);
        ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(binding);
        Context context = binding.getRoot().getContext();

        binding.nextItemBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (nextItemListener != null && position < getItemCount() - 1) {
                nextItemListener.onClick(position + 1);
            }
        });

        binding.lastItemBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            if (lastItemListener != null && position > 0) {
                lastItemListener.onClick(position - 1);
            }
        });

        binding.curItemPos.setText(String.format(Locale.CHINA,
                "%d", position + NumberUtils.INTEGER_ONE));

        Norm norm = mItems.get(position);
        Integer normType = norm.getNormType();
        binding.normNameTV.setText(norm.getName());
        if (Norm.NORM_TYPE_NORMAL.equals(normType)) {
            binding.normTypeIV.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_pure_color_gray));
            binding.normTypeTV.setText(R.string.text_common_norm);
        } else if (Norm.NORM_TYPE_KEY.equals(normType)) {
            binding.normTypeIV.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_pure_color_red));
            binding.normTypeTV.setText(R.string.text_key_norm);
        } else if (Norm.NORM_TYPE_ONCE.equals(normType)) {
            binding.normTypeIV.setImageDrawable(context.getDrawable(R.drawable.bg_pure_color_green));
            binding.normTypeTV.setText(R.string.text_once_norm);
        }

        binding.totalItemCount.setText(String.format(Locale.CHINA, "%d", getItemCount()));


        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.setOptions(mItems.get(position), position);
    }

    public interface OnClickListener {
        void onClick(int position);
    }

    private OnClickListener nextItemListener;
    private OnClickListener lastItemListener;

    public void setNextItemListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        this.nextItemListener = listener;
    }

    public void setLastItemListener(OnClickListener listener) {
        this.lastItemListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }

    static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        ItemEvaluateNormViewBinding mBinding;

        ViewHolder(ItemEvaluateNormViewBinding binding) {
            super(binding.getRoot());
            mBinding = binding;
        }

        void setOptions(@NotNull Norm norm, int position) {
            mBinding.nextItemBtn.setEnabled(norm.isEvaluated());

            mBinding.radioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener((group, checkedId) -> {
                norm.setEvaluated(true);
                norm.setCheckedId(checkedId);
                mBinding.nextItemBtn.setEnabled(true);
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: using `TextView.setText()` reduce the line number is ok. But add lines is not correct.

Comment: Issue is in your `item_evaluate_norm_view.xml`. Please post whole code of that file.

Comment: @nitinkumarp hi nitinkumarp, I've edited my question.